# Analogous property for $access on ContentViewArticle

Tags: php, joomla

I have been able to find the analogous j2.5 properties off of the `ContentViewArticle` class as I'm converting this j1.5 site -but I can't seem to find one for `$access` so I get this error at the moment:

> Undefined property: ContentViewArticle::$access

what's the analogous property in j2.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Joomla 1.6+ the old "access" system was replaced by a much more comprehensive ACL that uses the `#_assetts` table amongst other things.

There isn't really a direct mapping to the old mechanism as each site can now create it's own access and viewing levels that may have no bearing on the the original setup.

You can find [the ALC Tutorial here](http://docs.joomla.org/ACL_Tutorial_for_Joomla_1.6) which covers it in reasonable depth.

For working with the ACL system you will probably want to also read "[Adding ACL rules to your component](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_ACL_rules_to_your_component)"

As a general note, the [Joomla Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/) site has a good [Developer landing page](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers) that you may also want to check out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I understand correctly but assuming you're working on a template override you could create the $access property from the template.

```
$this->access = new stdClass;
$this->access->canEdit    = $this->user->authorise('core.edit', 'com_content.article.'.$this->item->id);
$this->access->canEditOwn = $this->user->authorise('core.edit.own', 'com_content.article.'.$this->item->id);
$this->access->canPublish = $this->user->authorise('core.edit.state', 'com_content.article.'.$this->item->id);
```